# Dynamic table name in where clause using a field from select

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to insert identifiers (numbers) into a temporary table which satisfy several conditions.
I use `insert into select` structure.
One of the conditions is the next. There are tables `received_posts_1(id,post_id), received_posts_2(id,post_id)`...
Each selected identifier is part of a table name with received posts. I need to add an `and` part into the `where` clause of the next form.

```
and not exists(select 1 from CURRENT_RECEIVED_POSTS_TABLE where id = device_id and post_id = post_id_)
```

The insertion is in `while` cycle. The stop condition is a needed count of identifiers to be inserted.

Comment: ...you'd need dynamic SQL to do so, SQL in general doesn't allow placeholders for tokens (only data).  Having a schema with numbered tables like this usually indicates a problem with your design.  Often, it's better to have a column for the given id...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having multiple tables with the same structure is generally a sign of a poor database design.  In general, it is much better to have a single table, with columns that distinguish what you are trying to do.

One approach is to create such a table using a view:

```
create view received_posts
    select 1 as which, r.* from received_posts_1 r union all
    select 2, r.* from received_posts_2 r union all
    . . .;
```

You can then use this table in your query.

A more efficient method is to repeat the exists, with the right conditions:

```
not exists(select 1
           from received_posts_1
           where id = device_id and post_id = 1) and
not exists(select 1
           from received_posts_2
           where id = device_id and post_id = 2) and
. . .
```

As mentioned in the comments, you can use dynamic SQL if you know which post table you need for a particular invocation of the query.